# Specflow: How to apply one example table to more than on Scenario outline

Tags: c#, automation, bdd, specflow

I Have a feature file with many different scenarios and I want to be able to feed my test data table into them. Many of these scenarios will be using the same data (i.e. a set of Personas)... I don't want to have to repeat the Examples table each time under the scenario outline.

I know you can use a regular data table in the Background, but I still want to be able to use scenario outlines which require an Example table.

Any one have any ideas on how to best handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gherkin doesn't provide a syntax to share scenario outline examples across scenarios.

SpecFlow+ (SpecFlow+Excel) has a feature, that allows you to attach the same Excel table to multiple scenarios:

```
@source:PersonaExamples.xlsx
Examples:
| Persona Name | Favorite Color |
```

You can find more examples here: http://www.specflow.org/plus/excel/getting-started/

And more documentation about SpecFlow+Excel here: http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Excel/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but definitely good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Effectively what you're asking for is an extra dimension to your table (at the file level), and unfortunately I don't believe there is one.

My approach when I was working with it, was to use code to generate my scenario tables for me- that way, you can flatten each multi-dimensional test into a single row, as you would if you had a composite primary key in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Common data I have in Backgound section

See http://www.isaacautodev.com/specflow/how-to-use-background-in-specflow